# Laravel Eloquent ORM aggregate functions from SQL

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, orm, laravel

I am working with Laravel 4 for a project.

I have two tables, 'auctions' and 'bids' and I want to fetch all the auctions with the lowest bid they have. (I would like to get all the 'bid' model)

I can write the query for each auction in SQlite like:

```
select *,min(bids.amount) from auctions,bids where auctions.id = bids.auction_id and auctions.id = 2 ;
```

I have setup the relations auction hasMany('Bids') and bids belongsTo('Auction') so that i can call

```
$auctions = Auction::with('bids')->get();
```

to get all the auctions with the Bids model nested in so that i can call

```
$auctions->bids
```

in my view to access the bids.

Since I don't want to fetch 100 bids and calculate the lowest in my views, what is the best way to move the minimum bid logic into the model?

**UPDATE**

Both solutions are valid, actually what worked best is putting this in the model

```
public function getLowestBidAttribute() {
        return $this->bids()->orderBy('amount','asc')->first();
}
```

Since keeps the rest of the app cleaner and I can define other methods for getting bids with different logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use accessor for this:

```
// Auction model
public function getLowestBidAttribute()
{
  return $this->bids() 
    ->remember(1) // cache the query for a minute
    ->orderBy('amount', 'asc')->first();
}
// you can also check isset() lowestBid on $this->attributes, but this is a bit cleaner
// and most of the time caching query for a minute will be enough to avoid multiple queries
```

Then you can access it as easy as:

```
$auction->lowestBid; // Bid model you need
```

---

edit: Above code is OK for a single auction, but when you fetch Collection of auctions, then it will cause n+1 issue and I would suggest processing it in the code instead, but that's not a problem:

```
// Auction model
public function bids()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Bid')->orderBy('amount','asc');
}
```

Then use first() method on the collection:

```
// $auctions = Auction::with('bids')->get();
foreach($auctions as $auction)
{
  $auction->bids->first(); // Bid model with lowest amount value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the auctions and fetch the min bid for each of them like this:

```
foreach($auctions AS $auction) {
     echo $auction->bids->min('bid');
}
```

a combination with deczo's answer is better and what you asked for, on the Auction model:

```
function getMinBidAttribute() {
   return $this->bids()->min('bid');
}
```

then you can call it like this:

```
foreach($auctions AS $auction) {
   echo $auction->minBid;
}
```

Comment: $auction->bids->min will not return model obj, but lowest value from the collection of all bids, the same goes for the 2nd code as it will fetch min value from db.

Comment: I thought he wanted the lowest bid, plus all the bids.

->minBid wil give him the lowest bid, and ->bids() will give him the bids collection.

Comment: bids() returns query builder, so bids()->min(...) runs aggregate SQL query ( SELECT MIN() ...), while to check on the collection: bids->min(...)